Asymptotic value of a factorized sequence
Background
Consider the following "output" sequence $p_k:\mathbb{N}\mapsto[0,1]^2$
\begin{equation}
p_k \triangleq \frac{1}{\Lambda_k} \left[\begin{array}{c}
\prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \\
\prod_{j=1}^k (1-\lambda_j)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
where the normalizer is
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_k \triangleq \prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i +
\prod_{j=1}^k (1-\lambda_j)
\end{equation}
and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ is a given "input" sequence such that $\lambda_k\in[0,1]$. I'm searching for the asymptotic equilibria of $p_k$. Currently, I believe that the following fact is true:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\to \infty} p_k =\begin{cases}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if } \lambda_k > 1/2 \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if } \lambda_k = 1/2 \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if } \lambda_k < 1/2 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_k>1/2$, $\lambda_k=1/2$, $\lambda_k<1/2$ are intended for all $k$ and $(\cdot)'$ is the transpose operator. The intuitive proof is as follows. For the case with $\lambda_k>1/2$, note that for large $k$
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \gg \prod_{i=1}^k 1-\lambda_i
\end{equation}
Consequently, for large $k$ it holds that $\Lambda_k \approx \prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$ and
\begin{equation}
p_k \approx \frac{1}{\prod_{\ell=1}^k \lambda_\ell}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \\
\prod_{j=1}^k (1-\lambda_j)
\end{array}\right]' \to \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]'.
\end{equation}
The proof for the case $\lambda_k<1/2$ is analogous, with the exception that
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \ll \prod_{i=1}^k 1-\lambda_i
\end{equation}
and the proof for the case $\lambda_k = 1/2$ is trivial.
The problem
I suspect that the requirements on $\lambda_k$ can be relaxed, in the sense that it is not strictly necessary that for all $k$ the sequence $\lambda_k$ has to be greater, equal or smaller than $1/2$. I'm not sure how to formalize the concept, but from an intuitive point of view what I want to say is that
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\lim_{k\to \infty} p_k =\begin{cases}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if "most of the" } \lambda_k > 1/2 \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if "most of the" } \lambda_k = 1/2 \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]' & \text{ if "most of the" } \lambda_k < 1/2 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where, practically speaking, by "most of the" $\lambda_k$ means that if we consider a finite sequence $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_K\}$ then "most of the" $\lambda_k$ are $1/2$ if $1/2$ is the most recurrent value in $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_K\}$.
I'm not sure, but I think that we have to work with subsequences, limsup, liminf, to formalize my "most of the" concept. Unfortunately, I'm not super familiar with this kind of subjects and I would like to have an hand to understand how to make the things work properly.
Questions
My questions are the following:

How do you formalize my intuitive concept of "most of the"?
Given a more rigorous definition of my "most of the" concept, is, in the given rigorous sense, $(1)$ true?
If $(1)$ is true in the rigorous sense, how do you prove it?

